# Asterisk in Title Issue

Tags: formatting, titles, preamble

I'm using overleaf for a paper and I'm using a journal template with the following in the preamble:

```
%
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
 ]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{Classifying Overlapping Galaxies For Weak Lensing Surveys}
```

The output on the title is

```
"Classifying Overlapping Galaxies For Weak Lensing Surveys*"
```

How do I get rid of the asterisk?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem... If I add `\maketitle` and `\end{document}` to the lines you posted, the title is displayed correctly, without any asterisk.

Answer (score 5):

Although you haven't shown this, remove `\thanks` that follows the `\title`, since it's used as an annotation for `\title` in the form of a footnote.

[image]

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
 ]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{Classifying Overlapping Galaxies For Weak Lensing Surveys}
%\thanks{Some title footnote}% This inserts a title-related footnote

\maketitle

\end{document}
```